# DFP Interstitial Ads isReady Property equal false

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, admob

I am using DFP Interstitial Ads when I check isReady property it's I found that it's value always equal false so, I can't present the 
interstitial ads

Answer (score 0):

To present interstitial ads below steps you need to follow.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/interstitial

and you can check this example that can help you

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples